# Why Laravel stores different times in timestamp

Tags: mysql, laravel

I us a simply Todo model with progress. When the progress is set to 100%, I like to store the timestamp and also the id of the closer.

But with `Carbon::now()` the time is different the `closed_at` column than in the `updated_at`.

```
    public static function updateTodo($todo)
    {
        self::updateClosedAt($todo);
        self::updateDueDateStatus($todo);
        self::updateStartDateStatus($todo);
    }

    public static function updateClosedAt($todo)
    {
        var_dump(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        if($todo->progress == 100 && !$todo->closed_at ) {
            $todo->update(['closed_at' => Carbon::now(), 'closer_id' => request()->user()->id]);
        }
        else {
            $todo->update(['closed_at' => null, 'closer_id' => null]);
        }
    }
```

The `var_dump` returns the correct time.

The row in the db:

[image]

[image]

Why the times are different?

Comment: TIMESTAMP datatype is timezone-dependent. Rather than DATETIME.

Comment: But how I have to handle it?

Comment: Different how? Seconds different? Exact hours different or the difference seems random?

Comment: `closed_at`: `2021-03-01 01:00:00` and `updated_at`: `2021-03-01 13:25:42`